# How to add styles to <body> dynamically in a ReactJS application without directly manipulating DOM

Tags: reactjs

We should not manipulate DOM directly in ReactJS because it maintains the virtual DOM. That's why we use props and states. But in my application I need to remove scrollBar from `<body>` on mobile devices when the navigation opens. How can I do that instead of doing `document.body.setAttribute('style', 'overflow: hidden')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting attributes on `document.body` is fine to do. React only manipulates the DOM of the trees it's rendering by itself (and those you shouldn't touch manually).

In other words,

```
function App() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    return () => document.body.style.overflow = undefined;
  }, []);
  return <>...</>;
}
```

is fine – this component will set the overflow attribute on `body` as a side effect when it mounts, and clear it when it unmounts.